# service/products for audio and video embedding

Tags: video-streaming, audio-streaming

What is the easiest solution that will allow me to embed audio and video on a webpage so that it will be supported by all recent browser versions (Firefox, Safari, IE) and devices (iOS, Android)? I've read a few things on stackoverflow and at other sources. Holy crap what a pain in the ass. Is there a service that will handle all the issues? I would just like to post the media files on my site or elsewhere then paste some code into a webpage. I'm willing to pay for a service (

Ideally I would like to post one file and have the service/product do whatever encoding is necessary to support compatibility.

Perhaps I am living in a fantasy world that is 5+ years in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For video, your best bet is YouTube.  Here is a video about how to embed with it http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnehCBoYLbc

For audio, try SoundCloud (soundcloud.com).  Here is how to post player links with it: http://en.support.wordpress.com/audio/soundcloud-audio-player/

Both use Flash, have specialized clients for devices, and are either currently or in the near future going to support HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

The solution we settled on is using http://vimeo.com for video which has a cheap yearly plan that allows for private videos and has a richly customizable player that we embed.

For audio we just use html5 and allow the user to download the mp3 file if they don't have html 5